# Countdown Timer doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

The target is: if there is a motion, the recording starts and the counter (x) begins to decrement every 1 second, but if in the meantime there is another motion, the counter restart to x (for example: 5 second).

Actually this doesn't work, more specifically, the counter doesn't reset if there's a motion during the recording, so every video has 5secs lenght.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep                                          
camera = PiCamera()
sensor = MotionSensor(7)
camera.hflip = True                                     

name = "video.h264"
x = 5 #seconds of record

def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print (count)
        count -= 1
        sleep(1)
        if sensor.when_motion == True:
           count = x

def registra_video():
    print ("recording started")
    #camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording(name)
    countdown(x)

def stop_video():
    camera.stop_recording()
    #camera.stop_preview()
    print ("recording stopped")

print("Waiting...")
sensor.when_motion = registra_video
sensor.when_no_motion = stop_video
pause()
```

P.s i know that i have to do a function that name every video differently, but i will do it subsequently.

Comment: Is `when_motion` supposed to be a function or a Boolean?

Comment: I don't undestand, from: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1.post1/api_input.html#gpiozero.MotionSensor:when_motion
The function to run when the device changes state from inactive to active.

This can be set to a function which accepts no (mandatory) parameters, or a Python function which accepts a single mandatory parameter (with as many optional parameters as you like). If the function accepts a single mandatory parameter, the device that activated will be passed as that parameter.

Set this property to None (the default) to disable the event.

Comment: I guess that `sensor.when_motion == True` is not what you want then. Because it's comparing a function reference against a Boolean

Comment: Also I think so, but What can I do instead of this?

Comment: You really need to consider multi threading this. I am not familiar with the particular package you are using, but I am pretty sure I see what's going on in the code well enough to answer your question.

Comment: I will do that within the next hour (on mobile now). I will put a lot of links to Python docs into my answer with a lot of explanation because there are going to be a bunch of topics that I am guessing are new to you.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately multithreading is new to me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Took a bit longer than an hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### INTRO

To begin with, I am pretty sure that this problem is best solved with a multi-threaded approach for two reasons. First of all, event handlers in general are intended to be small snippets of code that run very quickly in a single thread. Secondly, your specific code is blocking itself in the manner I will describe below.

#### Current Behavior

Before presenting a solution, let's take a look at your code to see why it does not work.

You have a motion sensor that is outputting events when it detects the start and end of a motion. These events happen regardless of anything your code is doing. As you correctly indicated, a [`MotionSensor`](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1.post1/api_input.html#motion-sensor-d-sun-pir) object will call [`when_motion`](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1.post1/api_input.html#gpiozero.MotionSensor.when_motion) every time it goes into active state (i.e., when a new motion is detected). Similarly, it will call [`when_no_motion`](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1.post1/api_input.html#gpiozero.MotionSensor.when_no_motion) whenever the motion stops. The way that these methods are called is that events are added to a queue and processed one-by-one in a dedicated thread. Events that can not be queued (because the queue is full) are dropped and never processed. By default, the queue length is one, meaning that any events that occur while another event is waiting to be processed are dropped.

Given all that, let's see what happens when you get a new motion event. First, the event will be queued. It will then cause `registra_video` to be called almost immediately. `registra_video` will block for five seconds no matter what other events occurred. Once it is done, another event will be popped off the queue and processed. If the next event is a stop-motion event that occurred during the five second wait, the camera will be turned off by `stop_video`. The only way `stop_video` will not be called is if the sensor continuously detects motion for more than five seconds. If you had a queue length of greater than one, another event could occur during the blocking time and still get processed. Let's say this is another start-motion event that occurred during the five second block. It will restart the camera and create another five second video, but increasing the queue length will not alter the fact that the first video will be exactly five seconds long.

Hopefully by now you get the idea of why it is not a good idea to wait for the entire duration of the video within your event handler. It prevents you from reacting to the following events on time. In your particular case, you have no way to restart the timer when it is still running since you do not allow any other code to run while the timer is blocking your event processing thread.

#### Design

So here is a possible solution:

1. When a new motion is detected (`when_motion` gets called), start the camera if it is not already running.
2. When a stop-motion is detected (`when_no_motion` gets called), you have two options:

   1. If a countdown is not running, start it. I would not recommend starting a countdown in `when_motion`, since the motion will be in progress until `when_no_motion` is called.
   2. If the countdown is already running, restart it.

The timer will run in a background thread, which will not interfere with the event processing thread. The "timer" thread can just set the start time, sleep for five seconds and check the start time again. If it is more than five seconds past the start time when it wakes up, it turns off the camera. If the start time was reset by another `when_motion` call, the thread will go back to sleep for `new_start_time + five seconds - current_time`. If the timer expires before another `when_motion` is called, turn off the camera.

#### Some Threading Concepts

Let's go over some of the building blocks you will need to get the designed solution working.

First of all, you will be changing values and reading them from at least two different [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). The values I am referring to is the state of the camera (on or off), which will tell you when the timer has expired and needs to be restarted on motion, and the start time of your countdown.

You do not want to run into a situation when you have set the "camera is off" flag, but are not finished turning off the camera in your timer thread, while the event processing thread gets a new call to `when_motion` and decides to restart the camera as you are turning it off. To avoid this, you use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects).

A lock is an object that will make a thread wait until it can obtain it. So you can lock the entire camera-off operation as a unit until it completes before allowing the event processing thread to check the value of the flag.

I will avoid using anything besides basic threads and locks in the code.

#### Code

Here is an example of how you can modify your code to work with the concepts I have been ranting about ad nauseum. I have kept the general structure as much as I could, but keep in mind that global variables are generally not a good idea. I am using them to avoid going down the rabbit hole of having to explain classes. In fact, I have stripped away as much as I could to present just the general idea, which will take you long enough to process as it is if threading is new to you:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread, RLock

camera = PiCamera()
sensor = MotionSensor(7)
camera.hflip = True                                     

video_prefix = "video"
video_ext = ".h264"

record_time = 5

# This is the time from which we measure 5 seconds.
start_time = None

# This tells you if the camera is on. The camera can be on
# even when start_time is None if there is movement in progress.
camera_on = False

# This is the lock that will be used to access start_time and camera_on.
# Again, bad idea to use globals for this, but it should work fine
# regardless.
thread_lock = RLock()

def registra_video():
    global camera_on, start_time
    with thread_lock:
        if not camera_on:
            print ("recording started")
            camera.start_recording('{}.{:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.{}'.format(video_prefix, datetime.now(), video_ext))
            camera_on = True
        # Clear the start_time because it needs to be reset to
        # x seconds after the movement stops
        start_time = None

def stop_video():
    global camera_on
    with thread_lock:
        if camera_on:
            camera.stop_recording()
            camera_on = False
            print ("recording stopped")

def motion_stopped():
    global start_time
    with thread_lock:
        # Ignore this function if it gets called before the camera is on somehow
        if camera_on:
            now = datetime.now()
            if start_time is None:
                print('Starting {} second count-down'.format(record_time))
                Thread(target=timer).start()
            else:
                print('Recording to be extended by {:.1f} seconds'.format((now - start_time).total_seconds()))
            start_time = now

def timer():
    duration = record_time
    while True:
        # Notice that the sleep happens outside the lock. This allows
        # other threads to modify the locked data as much as they need to.
        sleep(duration)
        with thread_lock:
            if start_time is None:
                print('Timer expired during motion.')
                break
            else:
                elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time
                if elapsed.total_seconds() >= record_time:
                    print('Timer expired. Stopping video.')
                    stop_video() # This here is why I am using RLock instead of plain Lock. I will leave it up to the reader to figure out the details.
                    break
                else:
                    # Compute how much longer to wait to make it five seconds
                    duration = record_time - elapsed
                    print('Timer expired, but sleeping for another {}'.format(duration))

print("Waiting...")
sensor.when_motion = registra_video
sensor.when_no_motion = motion_stopped
pause()
```

As an extra bonus, I threw in a snippet that will append a date-time to your video names. You can read all you need about string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [here](https://pyformat.info/#datetime). The second link is a great quick reference.

Comment: @Ermess I should mention that I did not test this code, so if you run into any bugs, I would be more than happy to help you fix them.

Comment: I don't really know how to thank you! Seriously, thank you very much for the explanation!! Very Kind.

But i get this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'camera_on' referenced before assignment` why? camera on is defined as false in the 20th line

Comment: i edited the comment, if you still want to help me :)

Comment: @Ermess. Sorry. The error happens when you write to a global variable without declaring it as global in the namespace. Will fix shortly. I keep running between different locations, so yeah, my response times are not great right now.

Comment: @Ermess. It's been a while since I've used globals like that, hence the oversight. Would you mind if I turned this code into a class? That would be the "proper" way to do it.

Comment: @Ermess. Updated the code. I changed things around to streamline the `timer` method a little bit

Comment: I don't understand the use of the variable `duration`; It appears the first time with this instruction `sleep (duration)`, but it has never been used...

Comment: @Ermess. You are right. I clobbered the initialization during one of my edits. Fixed now. Duratuon is the amount of time left to make the total wait 5 sec. If time has already elapsed from the last stop motion because we were sleeping, the remaining time needed to sleep will be less than 5 sec.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now i get this :( `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'`

Comment: @Ermess. Which line is raising that error? I thought I was calling that method on a time_delta object, not a date_time.

Comment: Nvm, got it. Change `elapsed = datetime.now()` to `elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time` (fixed in answer too)

Comment: Now the code run well, but I noticed that the duration never gets extended. I read and reread the code to understand the error, but I have not found it.
I'm sorry to bore you.

Comment: To do a Better troubleshooting, Is it possible to print the actual value of the sleep? Like my beginning program at line 12. If not, it does not matter.

Comment: @Ermess. Depends on what you mean by printing the value of the sleep. Do you mean `print('Going to sleep for {}'.format(duration))` right before `sleep(duration)`.

Comment: Nope, I thought to print the actual value of the sleep like a timer, as output: >>>5>>>4>>>3>>>2>>>1...but thinking about it, it isn't possible. I still do not understand the `duration` never gets extended

Comment: I added a couple of printouts to make it more apparent when the extension happens. Let me know if that helps any.

Comment: What makes you think that the duration never gets extended?

Comment: Thank you. now I understand better. I thought about that beacause: _1)_ if I make a motion, the duration of the video remain 5 seconds _2)_ I never get this `print('Recording to be extended by {:.1f} seconds'.format((now - start_time).total_seconds()))` when I do a motion.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but i need your help :( @Mad Physicist

Comment: No worries. I am not sure that I understand the exact issue. Could you print something like `print('Started motion')`, `print('Stopped motion')` as the first line of `registra_video` and `motion_stopped`, respectively, immediately after the `globals` statements? That will tell you if the stop-motion event gets activated at all.

Comment: I tried and i get both `print()`; I try to explain better the problem:
The purpose of the program is: if there is a motion, the recording starts and lasts e.g for 5 seconds, but if there is another motion before the end of 5 seconds contdown, the contdown have to restart to 5 seconds. If there is not another motion meantime, the contdown back to zero normally.

Comment: I thought I understood that correctly. Perhaps my model of how sensor works is not correct. My assumption is that `sensor.when_motion` is called when you start moving in front of the detector, and `sensor.when_no_motion` is called when you stop moving/the detector can't see you any more. I start the video as soon as the motion starts, but I don't set the time until `sensor.when_motion` gets called since you are moving in that interval. Any new calls to `sensor.when_motion` will actually clear the timer so the video continues, while new calls to `sensor.when_no_motion` will reset it to 5 sec.

Comment: The sesor has only two output: `HIGH` when detect a motion and `LOW` otherwise. Yes, `sensor.when_motion` is called when the PIR detect a motion and `sensor.when_no_motion` when nothing is detected.
I have manually set a low detection delay on the PIR, so the output will remain `high` for about 2 seconds